# Excel: Raising a value in one cell based on a value from another cell (For Work)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have tried using a few formula examples I found online, with no such luck. I am looking to create an easier testing sheet for my workplace to perform temperature tests in Fahrenheit based on standards with ambient temperatures. Main purpose is if the ambient temperature increases or decreases, the location being tested needs to reflect this.

Based on this, I am looking to create a formula where if a value increases or decreases in one cell, it will also reflect this based on another cell.

For example, in A1 I need the value to stay at 131. In cell B2, I need the cell to stay at 77. If 77 (77F) in B1 increases by 1 to 78, I would need cell A1 (131) to increase also by 1 to 132. If 77 were to drop to 76, I would then need 131 to go to 130.

Any examples or help on this, would be great.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but you need `A1` to stay at 131, but then you need it to scale with `B1`? For this example, couldn't you just put `=sum(131,B1-77)` in `A1`?

Comment: Actually I am agree with Christofer Weber, seems to enter `=131+B1-77` in A1 could achieve the result.

Comment: That will work thank you very much!